# Download file with japanese symbols in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, character-encoding, download, href

In javascript code i have to create a file with Japanese content and download it.
Here is my code

```
var downloadLink = $("<a target='_blank' href='data:text/plain;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(fileContent) + "' download='" + fileName + "'></a>");
someContainer.append(downloadLink);
downloadLink[0].click();
downloadLink.remove();
```

where `fileContent` contains japanese and english symbols: like "\"SomeEnglishWord\", \"somejapaneseword\"". When the code executes and i get my file downloaded i see some unknown, strange symbols instead of japanese words. for example

```
DataFormat.cs 複数ビューの機能を有効化します。
```

is converted to

```
DataFormat.cs è¤‡æ•°ãƒ“ãƒ¥ãƒ¼ã®æ©Ÿèƒ½ã‚’æœ‰åŠ¹åŒ–ã—ã¾ã™ã€‚
```

as i guess something is wrong with encoding, but can't solve my problem. please help
Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

try to declare meta charset to utf-8.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8 ">
...
</head>
```

Let me know if it works.
However, you can also set the specific japanese charset:
http://webcheatsheet.com/html/character_sets_list.php

EDIT:
Please, try this:

```
file_encoded = URLEncoder.encode(fileContent,"UTF-8");
var downloadLink = $("<a target='_blank' href='data:text/plain;charset=utf-8," + file_encoded + "' download='" + fileName + "'></a>");
someContainer.append(downloadLink);
downloadLink[0].click();
downloadLink.remove();
```

Comment: thanks for answer. i am using aspx files. when i open my page in chrome with debugger tool i can see <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8 "> already set in my page.

Comment: Try to setup charset=shift-jis

Comment: Uhm... ok.
Have you tried to change charset into your code?

   `code`var downloadLink = $("<a target='_blank' href='data:text/plain;charset=shift-jis," + encodeURIComponent(fileContent) + "' download='" + fileName + "'></a>");`code`

Comment: again the same result

Comment: You can try to change encodeURIComponent(fileContent) with encodeURI(fileContent)

Comment: I've just edited my first post. Please take a look. @artak-khachatryan